# Different xsubj dependency output from CoreNLP and stanford dependency parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using latest CoreNLP 1.3.5 . For the example sentence of xsubj dependency "Tom likes to eat fish", I am not getting a dependency xsubj(eat, Tom). Although I get a dependency xcomp(like, eat).

But I can see the dependency xsubj in the latest stanford dependecy parser 2.0.5 output for same sentence.
I tried copying some classes for parser, semgraph and Trees into the coreNLP jar from stanford parser jar. But still I could not get this outut.
Can anybody please guide me , how can I determine this relation.

Answer (score 0):

Are both using the same models? CoreNLP ships with several models (trained with different corpora), try checking them all.